# WordPress Ajax request "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, jquery

I spend a lot of time searching for a solution to this issue. I looked on google and stackexchange but didn't get the answer.

So I am looking for the solution is while making an ajax request through my plugin(that I am developing) i am getting this 400 status error.[image]
I don't know why i am getting this?

## 1 Scripts

```
function smn_admin_assets($page_now){    
    if( $page_now == "settings_page_smn_notice" ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'smn-admin-style', plugins_url( "../assets/admin/admin.css", __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'smn-admin-js', plugins_url( "../assets/admin/admin.js", __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), VERSION, true  );        
        $pass_value = array(
            'url'            => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'cookieNonce'    => wp_create_nonce('cookieNonce')
        );
        wp_localize_script('smn-admin-js', 'smn_ajax', $pass_value );
    }    
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'smn_admin_assets' );
```

## 2 Ajax Request

```
$(document).ready(function () {        

    $("#clearCookie").on('click', function(){
        var clearCookie = $('#clearCookie').val();
        // Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            url : smn_ajax.url,
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                action : 'smn_clear_cookie',
                clearcookie : clearCookie
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                alert('Hello');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert(smn_ajax.url);
            }
        });

        return  false;
    });
});
```

## 3 Ajax Handling

```
function smn_clearCookie(){

    $clearCookie = $_POST['clearCookie'];
    var_dump($clearCookie);

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_smn_clear_cookie', 'smn_clearCookie' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_smn_clear_cookie', 'smn_clearCookie' );
```

Let me know why i am getting this error;
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can clear cookies from the client side, you don't need PHP to do that. As an aside have you considered using the more modern/easier to debug REST API endpoints instead of the old archaic Admin AJAX interface? The REST API tells you in plain english what the problem is, unlike Admin ajax which returns cryptic responses

Comment: Hi, @TomJNowell thank you for your comment.
Actually, In this case, my plugin creates a cookie when someone first visits the site. So I want to add an option to this plugin admin page to clear the cookie and reset it by clicking on a button. This is why I am using ajax.

Comment: You can use AJAX in JS with the REST API, AJAX is just word for "Javascript contacting a web server". The REST API is superior in every way to the old admin ajax api. Also you can do what you're trying to do in javascript, no PHP needed, JS can set erase and change cookies